# Flask: automatically render templates if request URL matches their name

Tags: python, templates, flask

Can I have a structure within a Flask app's template directory that contains different templates each of which would be rendered if a request comes in that matches the location of the template within the template directory?

So if the template dir looks like this:

```
/template
  yellow
  red
  /blue
    black
    white
```

If a request comes in at example.com/yellow, then serve the `yellow` template; if a request comes in at example.com/blue/black, then serve the `black` template. Naturally, if there is no template to be found, return a 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`path:`](https://exploreflask.com/views.html#built-in-converters) to declare the type of variable that `template` will be in the routing:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index page'

@app.route('/color/<path:template>')
def template_router(template):
    return render_template(template + '.html')
```

So anything going to 'site/color/' will be caught and sent to the `template_router` method. From there, append *.html* if needed and attempt to load the template. You'll probably want to setup a method to catch 404s.

Your directory structure would look like:

```
.
├── app.py
└── templates
    ├── black.html
    └── blue
        └── black.html
```

Comment: Gotcha, I suppose this would work after some tweaking. Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in doing something similar. The issue I'm running into is my `url_for` links in my templates are not recognized. The only way I can see how to address this would be to change links to `url_for('template_router', template='black')`, but this isn't preferred in my case.

Answer (score 0):

why not make a parent template, and pass the color to it? So in your template, something like `colors.html`.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% if color == 'blue' %}
  # something here
{% endif %}
```

Then have a route like this

```
@app.route('/colors/<color_name>')
def color_template(color_name):
  return render_template('colors.html', color=color_name)
```

Comment: I used the colors as example file names, the files share nothing in common. Plus, I want them to be organized in a specific directory structure.